# Laravel validation: Must be a valid JSON string with the "json" rule

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation

I'm making a Laravel API, but I can't seem to send JSON data in one of the posts. I checked the other posts in StackOverflow, but it seems that my JSON request is correct, so I can't seem to find the error:

Here is the code in my Controller's method:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    "name" => "required|string",
    "colors" => "json",
     "sizes" => "json"
]);

if($validator->fails())
    return response()->json(["errors" => $validator->errors()], 400);
```

Here is the request body:

```
{
 "name": "Test",
 "colors": {
   "Man": "#0000ff",
   "Second": "#FF0000"
 },
 "sizes": {
   "titles": "20px"
 }
}
```

The error:

```
{
   "errors": {
       "colors": ["The colors must be a valid JSON string."],
       "text_sizes": ["The text sizes must be a valid JSON string."]
   }
}
```

What seems to be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Well you are passing an json object, not an json string. So for this to work I think you need to do `JSON.parse()`. So that you get something like `"\"colors\": {\n   \"Man\": \"#0000ff\",\n   \"Second\": \"#FF0000\"\n }"`

Comment: I tried doing this: 
"colors": "{'Main': '#0000ff','Secondary': '#FF0000'}" and it didn't work. Isn't this a valid json string?

Comment: No I think you need to use backslashes: "\"colors\": \"Man\": \"#0000ff\",\"Second\": \"#FF0000\" }". PS I meant `JSON.stringify()` ofcourse.

Comment: I see. Well, how can I stringify only JSON fields before I validate them?
Because I only want in my case, two properties to be JSON data.

Comment: @Tom Please make a response in the thread so that I can mark my post as answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you need to pass an JSON String instead of an JSON Object. This can be done either by `json_encode` or `JSON.stringify`.

As an answer on your last comment.:

You could either do this in your frontend application with `JSON.stringify` or you could implement an Form Request with an `prepareForValidation()`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#prepare-input-for-validation.

Where you would do an `json_encode()` on the json properties. Like:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'colors' => json_encode($this->colors),
        'text_sizes' => json_encode($this->text_sizes)
    ]);
}
```

Or in your case:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->merge([
        'colors' => json_encode($request->colors),
        'text_sizes' => json_encode($request->text_sizes)
    ]), [
    "name" => "required|string",
    "colors" => "json",
     "sizes" => "json"
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution, just use double quotes to represent a json string, and escape the double quotes inside the json:

`{ "name": "Test", "colors": "{\"Man\": \"#0000ff\",\"Second\": \"#FF0000\"}", "sizes": "{\"titles\": \"20px\"}" }`

This solve my issue sending json string from Insomnia Api rest.

Answer (score -1):

laravel have a convenient way to validate a request please follow these steps to make your own request and response for api
1-`php artisan make:request YourRequest`

> ### Then customize your request like this

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Requests;
    
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
    use Illuminate\Http\Response;
    
    class OrderRequest extends FormRequest
    {
    
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize(): bool
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules(): array
        {
    
            $rules = [
                'your filed name' => 'required',
                
            ];
            return $rules;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the error messages that apply to the request parameters.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function messages()
        {
            return [
                'your field name' => 'custom message',
              
            ];
        }
    
        /**
         * Handle a failed validation attempt.
         *
         * @param Validator $validator
         * @return void
         *
         * @throws ValidationException
         */
        protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
        {
            $error = collect($validator->errors())->collapse()->toArray();
            $errors = implode(' | ', $error);
            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(
                ['response' => ['status' => false, 'message' => $errors]],
                Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
        }
    }
```

this will solve error as recommended by laravel and its a professional way

then use this Request into controller .

### if you want to use your own code then

just use  `json_encode($this->text_sizes)`

Comment: Thank you, but this seems impractical when I only want two fields to validated instantly. I don't have any complex logic right now, so there is no need for me to make all of this.